# Can't able to get location of moblie in flutter of moblie

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, geolocation, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am trying to get location of mobile by flutter and i can't able to get the dimensions.
wheni am pressing the button op services null is getting.there are so many friends are getting this error and we can't able to solve it.please anyone one help me out of these trouble

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {


  void getLocation() async{
  Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  print(position);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            getLocation();
          },
          child: Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



    Error i get is like:-
    I/Surface (24964): opservice is null false
    I/Surface (24964): opservice is null false
    I/Surface (24964): opservice is null false
    D/DecorView(24964): onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@936a7df[MainActivity]
    I/Surface (24964): opservice is null false
```

Comment: Did you check using the return type as Future<void> instead of void only?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs on my emulator make sure you have done all the necessary setup for geolocation package which you can find [here](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#-readme-tab-). Double check you have added proper permission to android and iOS.

**Android**
 
 Android 
On Android you'll need to add either the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission to your Android Manifest. To do so open the AndroidManifest.xml file (located under android/app/src/main) and add one of t
he following two lines as direct children of the  tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**iOS**
On iOS you'll need to add the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to your Info.plist file (located under ios/Runner/Base.lproj) in order to access the device's location. Simply open your Info.plist file and add the following:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
```

If you have done all the proper setup the issue is not in that code

Comment: I already did this but i can't able to et the location of my phone

Comment: Like I said your code runs just to make sure your location is turned on on your emulator right?

Answer (score 0):

In Android put `FINE_LOCATION` instead of `COARSE_LOCATION`, I had the same issue but after changing that I got the location printed and the permission dialog box doesn't appear if you have already given the permission for the location for this app in your phone, but if you changed then [permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3iU2.jpg) dialog box also would appear.